# How to make the main (calling) thread wait for a child thread to complete execution?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Using: Delphi 10 Seattle, Win32 VCL forms application

I'm developing an updater application that checks for updates to one or more installed software applications, and when updates are found will download the updates in sequence. After each update is downloaded, it will install the update before proceeding to download the next update. The downloading bit is implemented as a thread class (descendant of TThread) and its constructor is as follows:

```
constructor TWebFileDownloaderThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; const AWebFileURL, ALocalFilePath: String;
  ACallBackProc: TProgressCallback; AProxySetting: TProxySetting);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);

  FWorkResult := False;

  FWebFileURL := AWebFileURL;
  FProxySetting := AProxySetting;
  FLocalFilePath := ALocalFilePath;

  FUpdateCallbackProc := ACallBackProc;
end;
```

The main thread creates and starts the downloader thread as follows:

```
procedure TfmMain.DownloadUpdateFromWeb(const AInstallerFileURL: String);
var
  internet_file_download_thread: TWebFileDownloaderThread;
begin
  internet_file_download_thread := TWebFileDownloaderThread.Create(True, AInstallerFileURL, FUpdateDownloadDir,
    UpdateProgressCallback, FProxySetting);

  internet_file_download_thread.OnTerminate := WebFileDownloaderThread_TerminatedMethod;
  internet_file_download_thread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  internet_file_download_thread.Start;
end;
```

My specific question is: How to make the main (calling) UI thread wait until a downloader thread completes, before creating a new downloader thread to start the next download?

I believe that there is some form of queuing required, but not sure how to implement it. Your tips and advice are much appreciated.

Comment: You should try as hard as you can to avoid this design. The completion *itself* should trigger the next job without a thread having to wait for the completion to trigger the next job.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz shouldn't threads be as independent from the 'outer world' as possible? Triggering another download thread seems to be without the responsibility of a download thread to me

Comment: @mjn That's completely the wrong way to think about it. Threads are just the vehicles that run the code. It's code that has responsibility, not threads. Whatever code does the downloading should then go on to do what needs to be done after the downloading without needing a thread to sit around waiting. It makes no sense to create a thread to do work and then wait for that thread to finish -- that extra thread serves no purpose.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz imho this is a task where a 'queue of threads' is a solution, and the main thread is controlling how many threads are executed in parallel (could be depending on CPU load or core count). Mixing the 'global' queue management and 'worker' code (in the thread execute method) then would be bad style imho.

Comment: mjn is correct. Its a queue of threads, in which only one thread executes at a time, and when its done, the next one should start. TOndrej's solution seems simple and easy to implement for me.

Comment: I am at no time creating all the threads in advance, so no threads remain idle. Read my question. When the download/install thread completes, then I need to create a new thread, and so on, until all the installers from all URLs have been downloaded/installed.

Comment: Your previous comment said "queue of threads". Hence my comment. Spawning threads over and again, needlessly, is probably best avoided.

Comment: Why not just process each item sequentially in the main thread?

Comment: Or perhaps i should have said in a single thread

Comment: @HughJones yes this would be possible. However I would start with a 'one thread per action' design and not recycle the thread. This avoids the housekeeping (cleanup) between processed items. Simple create a fresh and clean new thread instance, start it, and let it destroy itself after termination.

Comment: which suggests you could write a single thread executable which terminates on completion ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you have a list of URLs to download and install (obtained by previously performing a check for updates). You want to download updates from these URLs and install them one by one: download update 1, install update 1, download update 2, install update 2, etc.

Here's a possible design:

In your `WebFileDownloaderThread_TerminatedMethod`, start installing the just downloaded update (to keep the main thread responsive, do this in a separate thread).

In the `OnTerminate` handler of the installer thread, remove the just completed URL (or mark it as processed) and start downloading the next one, by calling `DownloadUpdateFromWeb` again, unless the list is already empty (or contains no more unprocessed items).

(BTW, the method `DownloadUpdateFromWeb` would better be named something like `BeginDownloadUpdateFromWeb`, to indicate its asynchronous nature.)

Comment: So, this means that a TStringList with the download URLs is passed to the installer thread from the main UI thread. Ok. Good enough for me.

Comment: What I meant was the installer thread only needs to know the single update to install (which has just finished downloading). This is similar to how the downloader thread only needs to know the single URL to download from.

Answer (score 3):

You should not block the main thread. So do not wait until the worker thread completes. Instead arrange for the worker thread to signal to the main thread when it has finished. For instance by:

- Sending a message, or
- Using `TThread.Synchronize`, or
- Using `TThread.Queue`, or
- Handling the `OnTerminate` event of the thread, or
- Some other form of inter-thread communication.

The `OnTerminate` looks like a pretty good option to me.

You might also consider using a higher level parallel library. For instance the RTL's parallel library, or OTL. That way you can avoid getting tangled up in the details of threads, and let the parallel library deal with such matters.

Were you to do this you could design your application with a producer/consumer architecture:

1. Create a threadsafe queue.
2. Create one or more download threads, these are the consumers.
3. The main thread, the producer, pushes download jobs onto the queue.
4. The consumer threads wait on the queue and when it contains jobs, the consumer threads pull off jobs and process them, by downloading the file.

This sort of design is very simple to implement using a high level parallel library.

Comment: He's using `OnTerminate` so he already does receive the notification when the thread is finished.

Comment: The producer/consumer architecture often makes the task more contained and easier to comprehend. Most of the time I delegate the producer part in a thread as well.